TabView used for Reels problem when append more items on scroll
I'm implementing an Instagram Reels style view on my app using a TabView that contains individual AVPlayers.
When I try to add other elements to my initial list (to simulate an Infinite Scroll) I get a quite strange effect: as you can see in the video, when the reel with id 98 is played, I add new reels to my list and it occurs both that the video currently playing appears "flashed", whether the audio of the previous video starts.

It appears that the TabView has re-rendered, but not correctly.
This is my code:
ReelsView:
GeometryReader { geo in
    TabView(selection: $currentReel) {
        ForEach(0..<items.count, id: \.self) { i in
            let reelModel = items[i]
            ReelPlayerView(reel: reelModel.reel, videoPlayerModel: reelModel.videoPlayerModel, width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .frame(width: geo.size.width)
                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 270))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
                .tag(i)
                .id(i)
        }
    }
    .id(items.count)
    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
    .frame(width: geo.size.height)
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
    .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width)
    .onChange(of: currentReel) { value in
        for i in items.indices {
            if i == value {
                items[i].videoPlayerModel.play()
            } else {
                items[i].videoPlayerModel.stop()
            }
        }
        
        if (currentReel == Int(items.count - 1)) {
            self.items.append(contentsOf: self.items) --> here I append the new items, when I'm at the half of scrolled items
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        if items[currentReel].videoPlayerModel.player != nil {
            items[currentReel].videoPlayerModel.play()
        }
    }
    .onDisappear() {
        items[currentReel].videoPlayerModel.pause()
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)

ReelPlayerView:
CustomVideoPlayer(hls: reel.video_url!) { videoPlayer in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        videoPlayerModel.player = videoPlayer
    }
}
.frame(width: width, height: height)

How can I solve it?
Update:
I've tried to remove .id(items.count), I get the effect you see in the attached video.


Unfortunately ForEach is not a for loop and you can't do id: \.self or items[i] or it'll crash, need to use a real unique identifier property key path.

@malhal Even if I remove  id: \.self doesn't work

What did you use for the id?

What happens if you update the array at currentReel == Int(items.count - 2)?

@Timmy, happens the same that you see in the last video
